# multidraggable not working on addclass

Tags: jquery, draggable, addclass

I'm trying to use this

```
<a href="https://github.com/someshwara/MultiDraggable">
multidraggable plug-in</a>
```

for jquery. I wan't to include another element to drag using addClass. It does not work. I actually just edited the example that was provided on the multidraggable github page to see if it works, and sadly it does not.

I have pasted this problem on

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfgCj/) so that you guys can understand it more.

Here's the specific part that uses addClass on the start of a drag

```
$(".d2").multiDraggable({ group: $(".d2"), startNative: function () {$("#addme").addClass("d2", 400, "duration")}, dragNative : function () {}});
```

What I am actually planning to use this is for a solitaire game that I'm making. When a user starts dragging a draggable card and if there are other cards that are stacked on that card, it should include those cards on dragging as well. I have been having this problem for a week now.

If you have other suggestion that I should do instead of this, it would be really appreciated. Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: You're calling `addClass` with three arguments, which is not valid. Refer to the [API docs](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to see exactly what it does and how to use it.

Comment: The biggest problem here is that the plugin only calls `startNative` after it starts dragging. It's too late to change the dragging group at this point.

Comment: It looks like multiDraggable doesn't have a good way to change the dragging group, so you might have to re-initialize it every time you want to change a dragging group. Even though you specify the group with a class-based selector (`$('.d2')`), it evaluated the selector when you initialized the plugin, and adding the class to new elements will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to use that multidraggable plugin and never quite got it to work.

Try `ui.multidraggable.js` from [here](http://www.myphpetc.com/2009/11/jquery-ui-multiple-draggable-plugin.html).  Then it's as simple as

```
$('.myClass').multidraggable();
```

Now to answer your question you can add elements in two ways:

- Use `$('#myId').addClass('myClass');`
- You can ctrl-click on the element and add it to the group.

Hope this helps.